# How can we change the Date Picker Format When the toggle set to All Day

Tags: ios, swift2

Just Making Calendar app which i have the same requirement as IOS calendar. In that All Day toggle Changes To Different Date Formatting And DatePicker Style is also different. How can i deal with that?.

[image]

Comment: Just great another date picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSDateFormatter and when user change the toggle update format of date using Date formatter and load new format in Picker.

Answer (score 0):

you have option to create another picker otherwise you have to define condition on the picker delegate to show the new date format or your required format . 
when you first time open the picker than the content would load on to the picker may be there is a chance when you pass the  command to change format than the picker is still showing previous content than you need to reload the picker content to update the picker content value and to show the updated format type content.
may this could help you.